How to make a VCL control have a fixed margin to another control?
In my form, there are two labels, the first label (Label1) is set to AutoSize=true, and its Caption may change from time to time. The second label (Label2) should have a margin 20px from Label1, even if Label1's size is changed. And the whole form should keep a 50px margin from the right of Label2.

I can implement this with codes:
label2.Left := label1.Left + label1.Width + 20;
Width := label2.Left + label2.Width + 50;

However, is there a way to implement without codes?

Use TRelativePanel as a container for the two labels and set Label2.RightOf to Label1, Label2.Margin.Left to 20 and Label2.AlignWithMargins to True

Nice, I wasn't aware of TRelativePanel. You would have to set the panel's Anchors to account for Form resizes. And it looks like the panel's AutoSize doesn't work correctly (at least in 12.1), so it cuts off Label1's text unless the AutoSize is disabled and the panel is resized manually to be larger than the longest text.

Thank you. Seems to be a great choice but TRelativePanel is not available in Delphi XE3? Also it falls in Windows category in Delphi 11, does that means it only works in Windows 10+?

@RemyLebeau - Yes, panel's AutoSize doesn't work correctly but there is simple workaround. After the control inside the panel changes its size: Panel.AutoSize := False; Panel.AutoSize := True;

@alancc TRelativePanel was added in Delphi 10.0 Seattle. And although it is designed for Windows 10+, it should also work for older Windows versions too (according to https://blogs.embarcadero.com/getting-started-with-the-new-windows-10-vcl-ui-controls-in-rad-studio-10-seattle/)

Not strictly without any code at all, no.  Well, not in your example, anyway.
VCL controls do have AlignWithMargins and Margins properties to control spacing between controls.  However, this takes effect only when the control's Align property is set to a value other than alNone, and the only value that makes sense in your example is alCustom, in which case you would have to write code in the Form's OnAlignInsertBefore and OnAlignPosition events, eg:
function TForm1.FormAlignInsertBefore(Sender: TWinControl; C1,
  C2: TControl): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (C1 = Label1) and (C2 = Label2);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormAlignPosition(Sender: TWinControl; Control: TControl;
  var NewLeft, NewTop, NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer; var AlignRect: TRect;
  AlignInfo: TAlignInfo);
begin
  if Control = Label1 then begin
    NewLeft := Label2.Left - 20 - NewWidth;
    NewTop := Label2.Top;
  end
  else if Control = Label2 then begin
    NewLeft := AlignRect.Right - 50 - NewWidth;
    NewTop := Label1.Top;
  end;
end;

A simpler option would be to position the Labels where you want, and then set their Anchors property to [akRight, akTop] instead of the default of [akLeft, akTop].  That will at least reposition the Labels automatically when the Form resizes, but you would still have to reposition Label1 manually whenever its Caption changes, eg:
Label1.Caption := ...;
Label1.Left := Label2.Left - 20 - Label2.Width;

Either way, you should now be able to freely set Label1.Caption to whatever you want, and even resize the Form, and the two Labels will be repositioned accordingly.

Thank you. The real case is much complex. There are several controls to be aligned one by one and adjust sizes & locations automatically.
